# failed during deployment on netlify with an error : Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2

Tags: npm, deployment, netlify, npm-build

12:02:27 PM: Build ready to start
12:02:29 PM: build-image version: a49edbc55fc722f80f6b85963a5060f8d043a844 (focal)
12:02:29 PM: build-image tag: v4.8.1
12:02:29 PM: buildbot version: 3eebc38122efab6c175df98627632780779354a6
12:02:29 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
12:02:29 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
12:02:29 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
12:02:29 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
12:02:29 PM: git clone https://github.com/Uvais-khan078/app-codeyogi-clone-typescript
12:02:30 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
12:02:30 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
12:02:31 PM: Starting build script
12:02:31 PM: Installing dependencies
12:02:31 PM: Python version set to 2.7
12:02:32 PM: v16.15.1 is already installed.
12:02:32 PM: Now using node v16.15.1 (npm v8.11.0)
12:02:32 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
12:02:32 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
12:02:32 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
12:02:33 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
12:02:33 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
12:02:34 PM: No npm workspaces detected
12:02:34 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
12:02:34 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
12:02:34 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.11.0
12:02:34 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
12:02:34 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
12:02:34 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
12:02:34 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
12:02:34 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
12:02:34 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
12:02:40 PM: added 309 packages, and audited 310 packages in 6s
12:02:40 PM: 126 packages are looking for funding
12:02:40 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
12:02:40 PM: found 0 vulnerabilities
12:02:40 PM: NPM modules installed
12:02:41 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
12:02:41 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
12:02:41 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
12:02:41 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
12:02:41 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
12:02:41 PM: Installing Go version 1.16.5 (requested 1.16.5)
12:02:45 PM: unset GOOS;
12:02:45 PM: unset GOARCH;
12:02:45 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.16.5.linux.amd64';
12:02:45 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.16.5.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
12:02:45 PM: go version >&2;
12:02:45 PM: export GIMME_ENV="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.16.5.linux.amd64.env"
12:02:45 PM: go version go1.16.5 linux/amd64
12:02:45 PM: Installing missing commands
12:02:45 PM: Verify run directory
12:02:46 PM: ​
12:02:46 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:02:46 PM:   Netlify Build
12:02:46 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:02:46 PM: ​
12:02:46 PM: ❯ Version
12:02:46 PM:   @netlify/build 27.1.6
12:02:46 PM: ​
12:02:46 PM: ❯ Flags
12:02:46 PM:   baseRelDir: true
12:02:46 PM:   buildId: 62b55a7b9b455140f881bcfd
12:02:46 PM:   deployId: 62b55a7b9b455140f881bcff
12:02:46 PM: ​
12:02:46 PM: ❯ Current directory
12:02:46 PM:   /opt/build/repo
12:02:46 PM: ​
12:02:46 PM: ❯ Config file
12:02:46 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
12:02:46 PM: ​
12:02:46 PM: ❯ Context
12:02:46 PM:   production
12:02:46 PM: ​
12:02:46 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:02:46 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app
12:02:46 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:02:46 PM: ​
12:02:46 PM: $ npm run build
12:02:47 PM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
12:02:47 PM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
12:02:47 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
12:02:47 PM: > app-codeyogi-clone@0.0.0 build
12:02:47 PM: > tsc && vite build
12:02:47 PM: sh: 1: tsc: not found
12:02:47 PM: ​
12:02:47 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:02:47 PM:   "build.command" failed
12:02:47 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
12:02:47 PM: ​
12:02:47 PM:   Error message
12:02:47 PM:   Command failed with exit code 127: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-127)
12:02:47 PM: ​
12:02:47 PM:   Error location
12:02:47 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
12:02:47 PM:   npm run build
12:02:47 PM: ​
12:02:47 PM:   Resolved config
12:02:47 PM:   build:
12:02:47 PM:     command: npm run build
12:02:47 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
12:02:47 PM:     environment:
12:02:48 PM: Creating deploy upload records
12:02:47 PM:       - CI
12:02:47 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
12:02:47 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
12:02:49 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
12:02:47 PM: Caching artifacts
12:02:47 PM: Started saving node modules
12:02:47 PM: Finished saving node modules
12:02:47 PM: Started saving build plugins
12:02:47 PM: Finished saving build plugins
12:02:47 PM: Started saving pip cache
12:02:47 PM: Finished saving pip cache
12:02:47 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
12:02:47 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
12:02:47 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
12:02:47 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
12:02:47 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
12:02:47 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
12:02:47 PM: Started saving rust rustup cache
12:02:47 PM: Finished saving rust rustup cache
12:02:47 PM: Started saving go dependencies
12:02:47 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
12:02:48 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
12:02:48 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:02:49 PM: Finished processing build request in 20.062966026s

Comment: I think you’re missing tsc in package.json

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.